# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown when running jar file

Tags: java

I am trying to run my jar file on a Mac (Haven't yet tried on any other platform). When I run using java -jar MyApp.jar I get the following error

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
at tabalchi.MyLogger.getLogger(MyLogger.java:51)
at tabalchiApp.TabalchiApp.printSystemProps(TabalchiApp.java:117)
at tabalchiApp.TabalchiApp.main(TabalchiApp.java:37)
```

So, as you can see the main class is recognized.
This is the manifest file. 
--->

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar jars/jfugue-4.1.0-20120125.jar jars/gervill.jar jars/AppleJavaExtensions.jar  
Main-Class: tabalchiApp.TabalchiApp
SplashScreen-Image: tabalchiApp/resources/splash.png
```

<---
And the folder structure in the jar file as follows. 
--->

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jars/AppleJavaExtensions.jar
jars/gervill.jar
jars/jfugue-4.1.0-20120125.jar
jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar
tabalchiApp/TabalchiApp.class   <-- this is the main class
tabalchiApp/otherClasses.....class
```

<---

I have read many posts about running .jar file but none of the solutions have worked for me. I would really appreciate your help on this one.

I am creating the jar file by exporting from eclipse. If I export to a runnable jar file then I cannot control the making of the manifest file. I need to add the splash image in the manifest file. And I am having some other issues with the runnable jar export. Hence this path.

Comment: you need to have log4j into your classpath

Comment: Use maven for building runnable jars. It's very simple!

Comment: Are you able to run your code from your IDE?

Comment: Yes, the code runs fine from the IDE

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `log4j` is missing.it is expecting `jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar` in class path .

```
jars/log4j-1.2.16
```

should be under folder structure.

```
 jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part. It is in fact the log4j-1.2.16.jar that is in the jars directory.

Answer (score 0):

In which directory are you trying to use:
 java -jar MyApp.jar

You can specify the packages/directories in the classpath to be sure they are found.

Comment: the jar file is on the desktop. I am running this from the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so according to this link,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if MyJar.jar contains another JAR file called MyUtils.jar, you cannot use the Class-Path header in MyJar.jar's manifest to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path.

So, it seems I cannot include other jar files in my jar file.